# Troubleshooting java app

Tags: java

I looked through several postings, but didn't see anything that related to this specifically.  If there is a thread, would you please post a link?

I have written a java app.  It has a basic gui that gathers user preferences, then downloads files from the web based on those preferences.  It works just fine in eclipse.  It works just fine when I export into a .jar file on the same machine it was developed on.  However, when I try to load it on a different machine, it brings up the gui and gathers information, then just hangs.  It's irritating because I cannot troubleshoot the problem.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to have this problem, so I equally sure there are tools out there to help me, but since I've taught myself up to this point, I've not come across any.  Does anyone have any recommendations about what I might try, please?

Comment: Make sure that both machines are running the most recent update of the desired Java version.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I meant to say I had updated java first.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, on the assumption that you thought remote debugging required different/specialised tools.  It doesn't - you can connect to a remote app just as well as something on your dev box, if you supply the right system properties (as described in the linked question).

Comment: (Alternatively, if you did mean the question in the sense of "what sort of things might I want to look at to work out what's wrong", then this question would be too broad, and likely to solicit opinions and guesswork.  So it'd be closed on those grounds too.  If you find a **specific** anomaly with your debugging that you can't explain, then that would make a good question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your application on different machine in **debug** mode , and then you can use **Remote Eclipse debugger**, such as usual **web application debugging**.

Article about eclipse remote debugger is [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html)

Comment: The article gives me a start.  The author breezes over several parts that I need more information on, but I didn't even realize this existed in Eclipse.  Thank you for the response.